# How to remove the ports from my include files from my file using Verilog::SigParser

Tags: perl

I'm using Verilog package in Perl, so I can read a Verilog file and extract the ports the are inside. For this purpose, I'm using Verilog::SigParser, if you are new here you should know that Verilog::SigParser provide callbacks for when a signal is declared, a module instantiated or a module defined. The file you are passing is obviously a Verilog file. The problem here is I I'm trying to use SigParser in a file which includes inside another file (just it's name, not its content, scroll down for better understanding), and it looks like ports from the include file are getting inside my %arr(), which later on gives me some mistakes because of course I can't form the testbench. So let me show you some code:

**This is my perl file:**

```perl
#On top of the file
package MyParser
use Verilog::SigParser

$filename = /user/home/verilog.v
....

use base qw(Verilog::SigParser);
my %arr = (); #In this array, all module inputs and outputs are being saved.


#Process my verilog file
my $vf Verilog::Preproc->new(keep_comments->0);
$vf->open(filename=>$filename) or die $!;

open(FH,'>',/users/home/port_file);
print(FH, %arr()); #HERE IT IS INCLUDING NOT JUST THE PORTS FROM VERILOG.V BUT ALSO THE ONES FROM HAPPY.VP, I want only the ones from verilog.v
close(FH);
```

**Top file verilog.v**

```
`include happy.vp

module top();
.
  #lots of inputs and outputs
.
.
endmodule
```

**File happy.vp**

```
module happy();
  #some other inputs or outputs I don't want in my ports file. 
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

A SystemVerilog package cannot access any date type or data item declared outside of the scope of that package except via import from another previously compiled package. There is no way to import from a compilation unit.

```
typedef int t; // outside space is part of some compilation unit
package p;
   t v; // reference to t is illegal
endpackage
```

Comment: @anasan what is a *package reference*? package is just a name space. You can import it and use its members.

Comment: You cannot use the `import` statement inside a class--there are ambiguities in how import would work with inheritance. But you can explicitly reference a package member with `pkg_name::item_name`.